# service stops when app is swiped off

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to play an mp3 when app is closed. It works when I'm out of the app but when i swipe it off from task manager the song ends. How can I make the service continue playing after close? 
This is my service:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.d("MusicService", "onTaskRemoved");
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

This is my main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.gucci);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
            mp.start();

        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.pause();
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have a look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47828122/4168607)

Comment: Activities are (generally) destroyed when not showing. If you want some code to exist off-screen,  take a look at services.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work... @ADM

Comment: If you are building Music player kind of functionality then go for Foreground Service. Its the Only optimal option .

Comment: No, I have a school homework.. I just need a single mp3 file to continue playing after app closed

Comment: check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47812674/8117793

Comment: Use a foreground service, via `startForeground()`. You need that on Android 8.0+ anyway, or your service will be stopped after a minute.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Other way may be not usable (ignore if not usable).

Don't give user the option to clear it from recents menu.

Use this manifest attribute for each activity component in your Player app

**android:excludeFromRecents**

Comment: that might work, but is an ugly workaround in fact
Anyway - the Activity is going to die in background in some time.

Comment: Ugly workaround - yes it is. I already added a note for that.

Answer (score -1):

just return START_STICKY in onstartcommand method  of your service class . it will run forever in background .

Comment: @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,  int flags, int startId) {



      
                
        return START_STICKY;
    }

Thats how i usually do .. it works for me every time